# Definition of $\{t\in T: X(t) = u\}$, where $\{X(t): t\in T\}$ is a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition

Maybe this is a silly question, but it's important that I understand this. I just started to read the book *Level Sets and Extrema of Random Processes and Field*, from Jean-Marc Azais and Mario Wschebor. In the very beginning there is this.

[image: a]

Denote by $M$ the range space of the process $\mathcal{X}$. From my understanding, for each $t\in T$, we have that $X(t):\Omega\to M$ is a random variable.

Fixing $u\in M$ in the range space, I can understand the notation $\{X(t) = u\}$, which is $\{\omega\in\Omega: X(t)(\omega) = u\}$ more precisely. But the set $\{t\in T: X(t) = u\}$ is strange to me. They are saying this is a set of parameters $t$ such that $X(t)=u$. But $X(t)$ is a function, not a value! If we want to write precisely what this set is, I can see two possibilities.

**1)** $\{t\in T: X(t) = u\} = \{t\in T: X(t) \textrm{ is a constant function such that } X(t)(\omega) = u \textrm{ for all } \omega\in\Omega  \}$

**2)** $\{t\in T: X(t) = u\} = \{t\in T: \textrm{ exists }\omega\in\Omega \textrm{ such that } X(t)(\omega) = u \}$

Is any of this interpretations correct? If not, what is the correct interpretation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it is a *random* set, i.e., it is a function of $\omega$, or a random variable.
Perhaps this notation may help you understand:
$$\{t \in T : X(t) = u\}(\omega) := \{t \in T : X(t)(\omega)=u\}$$

Comment: So for each sample $\omega$ this function gives a random set in $T$. So we can write this function as $\Phi:\Omega\to\mathcal{P}(T)$, such that $\Phi(\omega) = \{t\in T: X(t)(\omega) = u\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(T)$ is the set of all subsets of $T$. Is this right?

Comment: @Integral Yes, that is how I interpreted it.

Comment: Just one more question. Is there a standard sigma algebra I should consider in $\mathcal{P}(T)$ ?Thanks!

Comment: @Integral I am actually not sure...

Comment: Maybe I can say that $A\subset\mathcal{P}(T)$ is measurable if, and only if, $\Phi^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$.